# Adding hours in PHP validating holidays

Tags: php, hour

I have a PHP code that generates delivery date and time of an order in my system validating schedule and sundays, in this way:

```
<?php
$hours = 6;

$date = date('Y-m-d h:i A');
$delivery = date("d-m-Y h:i A", strtotime("+$hours hours", strtotime($fecha)));
echo $delivery;

    if (date('H') >= 18 || date('H')<9 || date('w')==0){
        $c=strtotime("tomorrow 09:00");
        $date = date("Y-m-d h:i A", $c);

        $delivery = date("d-m-Y h:i A", strtotime("+$hours hours", strtotime($fecha)));

        echo $delivery;
    }


?>
```

This validates if an order is made after 6pm or before 9am or if current day is Sunday, the order goes to the next day at 9am and incrementing hours. But I want to validate if current day AND the next day is Sunday or holidays like 4th July (04-07) or Xmas (25-12) to generate delivery date time in the next day of them (05-07 or 26-12).

How can I modify it?

I would like some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run your code in a while-loop so you can call `tomorrow 09:00` as many times as necessary:

```
$hours = 6;

$orderPickup = time(); // Normally order should be picked up right now
$delivery = strtotime("+$hours hours", $orderPickup);

while(
    date('H', $orderPickup) > 18 
    || date('H', $orderPickup) < 9 
    || date('w', $orderPickup) == 0 // No order pickup on sunday
    || date('m-d', $orderPickup) == '12-25' // No order pickup on Christmas-day
    || date('w', $delivery) == 0) // No delivery on sunday
    || date('m-d', $delivery) == '12-25' // No delivery on Christmas-day
) {
    // $orderPickup will be 9 am next day
    $orderPickup = strtotime('tomorrow 9:00:00', $orderPickup);
    $delivery = strtotime("+$hours hours", $orderPickup);

    // If tomorrow 9:00 is stil not suitable, the while-loop will run again
}
echo "Delivery on " . date("d-m-Y h:i A", $delivery);
```

Comment: I use this code, but if i make the order in 12-24 at 13:00pm the result show 12-25 day, how can I fix it to put in the next day?

Comment: @NekoLopez Wouldn't be an issue with `$hours = 6` ;) -- I've modified the answer to have it check both order-pickup time and delivery time.

Answer (score 0):

First I would use DateTime objects. As next step you could separate the validation part from the modifying part. Run the validaton in a loop. Today, tomorrow and so an. Probably you will need a temporarily date object which you can modify without lose the origin date.